# Computing the geodesic distance of all pairs in point cloud

Tags: distance, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to find a method to compute the geodesic distance of every two pairs of points in a point cloud.
 I tried finding the relevant API in `PCL` or `PCLpy` but all the examples I found compute the euclidean distance .
I understand that computing the geodesic distance of a point cloud is not well defined, and only approximations are available, but nomerous papers have tried to preform such forms ( `fast marching method`, `heat method` etc.)